# Network bridge, 'Waiting for network configuration', Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-bridge

I'm trying to setup a network bridge in Ubuntu between my ethernet card and a usb-ethernet adapter.

When I boot Ubuntu from a USB flash (a real install with GRUB, not Ubuntu-Live) I get the line "Waiting for network configuration...", and later "Waiting 60 more seconds for network configuration...", and later "Booting without full network configuration". The two ethernet ports eth0 and eth1 are not bridged, which is what I want them to be.

Here are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
  address 192.168.100.91
  gateway 192.168.100.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging

I needed the package:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

and the `/etc/network/interfaces` had to be:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.10
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports eth0 eth1
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

and the `br0` interrface needed to be brought up using:

```
sudo ifup br0
```